# MySql Update Format and Syntax

Tags: mysql

Been at the second part of this problem for quite a long time for mysql, and I was wondering, what am I doing wrong. The problem is:

Insert a new record into the members table using any valid data and update xrefartistsmembers to make the person a member of Sonata.

I was able to get the first part no problem, and was able to insert the following into members

```
INSERT INTO Members (MemberID, FirstName, LastName, Address, City, Region, PostalCode, Country, HomePhone, WorkPhone, EMail, Gender, Birthday, SalesID)
VALUES (39, "John", "Smith", "449 S Hobart Blvd", "Los Angeles", "CA", 90025, "USA", 3235912274, 3103792865, NULL, "M", "1980-02-12", 4)
```

Now when I try to do the second part, I keep getting no changes. Am I anywhere close, or am I far off?

```
UPDATE Xrefartistsmembers X, Members M, Artists A
```

`SET M.MemberID = 5` 
 `WHERE M.MemberID = X.MemberID`
 `AND A.ArtistID = X.ArtistID`
 `AND Artistname = "Sonata"`
 `AND M.Firstname = "John"`

Comment: What's the table you want to update, xrefartistsmembers ?

Comment: Yes, I had to update it so that I can make the new person who I inserted into members, a member of Sonata, which is an artist.

Comment: can you post the structure of the table Xrefartistmembers?